# How to reference literalControl in masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a literal control in a masterpage that I would like to find from the child page and populate, but it always comes back null

```
[MasterPage]
  <asp:Literal ID="litStreamHtml" runat="server" />



[Child Page]
    LiteralControl litStreamHtml = Master.FindControl("litStreamHtml") as LiteralControl;
    litStreamHtml.Text = "some text";
```

Comment: what is the parent control of litStreamHtml ? FindControl does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls

Comment: The literal is just in a masterpage. As far as I know it isn't in any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh... The problem was I was using LiteralControl, instead of Literal. I didn't know there was a difference.

```
Literal litStreamHtml = (Literal)this.Master.FindControl("litStreamHtml");
    litStreamHtml.Text = "some text";
```

Comment: of course there is difference.`LiteralControl` donest use ViewState between postbacks meanin every time recreated.`Literal` uses ViewState.